# How to filter out all valid typed values from an optional typed array in Ballerina

Tags: filter, option-type, ballerina

How to filter all valid typed values from an optional typed array in Ballerina? This can be done using `foreach` like below,

```
int?[] input = [1, 2, (), 3, 4, ()];
int[] output = [];
foreach int? i in input {
    if (i is int) {
        output.push(i);
    }
}
```

But, how to achieve this using `filter`? I tried the below, but it gives a compilation error,

```
int?[] input = [1, 2, (), 3, 4, ()];
int[] output = input.filter(i => (i is int));
```

What am I doing wrong here? Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`filter`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.array/latest#filter) works on an array of `T` to construct another array of `T`. It is not possible to change the type of the new (filtered) array since the predicate function may return `true` for any of the members from the original array.

You could use a query expression instead.

```
int[] output = from int? i in input where i is int select i;
```